# Embed Powershell in notepad ++

Tags: plugins, notepad++, powershell, embedded

after playing about with Ubuntu 10.04, one of the interesting things I noticed was that you could embed a terminal in gedit. Is there a similar plugin that would enable me to embed a Powershell (or a command prompt) window into notepad ++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, PowerShell_ISE.exe (which comes with PowerShell), PowerGUI, PowerShell Plus, and Visual Studio all have PowerShell consoles below the editors ... and can use PowerShell to manipulate the IDE.

But what you're asking for is the NppExec plugin http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/ ... although it cannot manipulate the IDE ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should try **PowerGUI Editor**.

It autocompletes commands and variables and other nice stuff. And it if free.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't as far as I can see, why not switch to a Powershell window or use a real IDE?

Eclipse can do this for example...

---

**Edit:** Maybe [gedit for Windows](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Windows) is a better option! :-D

Comment: Yeah, notepad++ isn't an IDE. It's great for quick tests and text editing/highlighting, but it isn't designed for real development.

Comment: Wasn't happy with the answer, went to search and saw that gedit can be used on Windows. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Powershell you should look at a more powerfull IDE. [PowerGui.Org](http://powergui.org/index.jspa) makes a great free [system management](http://www.zdnetasia.com/simplify-powershell-script-creation-with-powergui-62049628.htm) and [script editor](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Script_Editor).

Answer (score 1):

NotePad++ comes primed with the NppExec plugin.
One of its many features is a Console Window... It has its quirks, but it may suit your needs.
I've found it most useful when it is associated with a shortcut such as CTRL+~
Tied to the Dialog-Toggle internal-command, CTRL+~ makes the console very accessible.  (of course the choice of shortcut-keys is personal)
You can set the window's properties (size, colour, and more) via
   menu --> Plugins --> NppExec ...
The shortcut-hotkey can be set via
   menu --> Settings --> Shortcut mapper --- Plugin Commands -- Toggle Console Dialog
   The items in the list are displayed  (but not labeled) in per-Plugin-groups, so they seem a bit random...

I haven't quite worked out "what and why", but I've found that I need to shell-out (in the same window) to start some commands.. eg. prompt> cmd /c tr.exe --help
It is not identical to the NotePad++ edit windows; it has copy/paste and its own Find-bar (Firefox-style).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This has become hard to find, so download it!

Link from official source *(note that clicking on this link will immediately download the file)*:

http://community-downloads.quest.com/powergui/Release/3.8/PowerGUI.3.8.0.129.msi

Comment: Is Community Downloads the official source?  Please see the guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Also, it would be better to use a link to a download site where the user can get informed and choose whether to download.  A hot link that immediately downloads an unknown file from an unknown source is a hazardous practice.  Thanks.

Comment: As I stated, The soft is hard to find, not updated since 2014 I think. Last official link point to community-downloads.quest.com. I tried to get to this page with no success, no choice but provide a direct link from the official source. Also Quest is the official developer of this software. My bad, I didn't know about sharing only open-source software, I just wanted to share it.